# How to delete/clear old commit history from pull request?

Tags: github, git-branch, pull-request, git-commit, git-rebase

After a pull request and merge from my remote origin branch to upstream, I deleted the branch from my remote, but I rename the local branch and keep working on it (which I think is the reason why I messed up). When I commit this local branch to remote origin and did a pull request to the upstream, my commits of the first pull request also appeared.

1. Are there ways to remove the old commit history from this pull request?
2. Or I have to close this pull request and rebase the local branch to the upstream before doing another pull request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have started working from an old branch (here a PR one), move your commits on top of the upstream target branch (for instance, the original repo `main` branch)

```
cd /path/to/repo
git remote add upstream https://github.com/<origina>/<repo>
git fetch upstream
```

You start from

```
   old PR
     |
--x--x--Y--y--y (newBranch)
      \
       m--m--m (upstream/main, updated by the fetch)
```

A quick rebase:

```
git switch myNewBranch
git rebase --onto upstream/main firstNewCommit^1 myNewBranch
```

That gives:

```
   old PR
     |
--x--x
      \
       m--m--m (upstream/main)
              \
               Y'--y'--y' (newBranch)
```

A `git push --force` and your new PR is updated with a much shorter history.

Answer (score 0):

if your changes has not been pushed yet you can simply use

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Alternatively, if you have already pushed your changes you can use this command

```
git push origin HEAD --force
```